# How do I work with noisy real world text data for text classification?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bert, text

I have a topic classification model built upon Bert, when I deploy my model people input strings of a random nature like :

"aaaaaa" "aaa bbb" "ab ab ab"

and so on.

My model predicts a false positive for these types of inputs 10% of the time. How do I make my machine learning model robust to these inputs?

Comment: a filtering process can be used, to filter out nonsense text. But in general people can outsmart any ML model, so there will be some false positives anyway

Comment: In general any method is valid only with the type of input data it's meant for, so I would say that this kind of problem can be ignored (if you put coffee in a photocopier, don't complain that you don't obtain a good copy of the coffee ;)). If you really must deal with this problem (I wouldn't), you could try to use open-set classification: in this case there is a default class kind of like "not applicable".

Comment: @Erwan Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into adding a default class!

Comment: Real open-set classification is different from regular multiclass classification, but yes you could try with a regular default class and see if it works.